# Concat javascript with interpolation Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Has anyone ever had this kind of problem?
I have the variable script.Id that comes from the script object in my Lista

But when I try to concatenate this value to pass as parameter in my url of windows.open appears the following error below:

[image]

My code in HTML:

[image]

But if I leave a fixed id in my url, the system redirects correctly.

Comment: why didn't you use (click)="somefunction(scriptId)"? Your solution is so dirty... Secondly, it is better when you insert code as text, not screen

Comment: I tried to use it, but I can not access windows.open inside my component

Comment: yep, you have to create service to gettin window. Here is a full tutorial: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/ Don't forget that in new versions angular you should use providers in module, not component

Comment: @FabioMijas Please avoid images in the questions if possible, in this case please use the the code section to paste your existing code and the error, you will get a faster answer this way, and please take a look to this thread for better questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: why you dont follow the advises of the error and use `(click)=` instead of `onClick=` ?????

Comment: Sirs, thank you very much for the tip.

Using the service according to @JaroslawK. indicated solved the problem.
Apologies for the confusion in creating my question, I am new here.

Greetings.

Comment: Classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) XD. Glad your problem was solved

Comment: Post the code, not an image of your code.